# Interval of sequence of natural numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

**Question**

Consider the sequence $(a_{n})_{n\geq 1}$ defined by $a_{1}\in (-1,1)$ and for every
$n\in \mathbb{N}^{*}, a_{n+1}=\sqrt{1+n\cdot a_{n}}$

Show that for every $n\in \mathbb{N}^{*}, a_{n}\in (n-2,n).$

**Attempt**

I tried to square both parts and divide by $n^2$ in order to obtain the form $\frac{a_n}{n}$ that I need to calculate it limits later but it does not lead me to any useful results in proving what I need to prove.

I also tried to use induction but it doesn't seem useful in this case.

Any hint would be very helpful to me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Induction is very useful in this case.  Assume $a_n$ is in the required range.  Then what are the minimum and maximum $a_{n+1}$ can be?

Comment: Use induction and $a^2+2ab+b^2 = (a+b)^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's prove by induction on $n\geq1$. So for $n=1$ this is given. Assume that $a_n\in(n-2,n)$. We want to show that $\sqrt{1+na_n}\in(n-1,n+1)$. Note:
$$a_{n+1}=\sqrt{1+na_n}>\sqrt{1+n(n-2)}=\sqrt{1-2n+n^2}=\sqrt{(n-1)^2}=n-1$$ Where the inequality is true since $a_n>n-2$.
Similarly:
$$a_{n+1}=\sqrt{1+na_n}<\sqrt{1+n^2}\leq\sqrt{1+2n+n^2}=\sqrt{(n+1)^2}=n+1$$
So $a_{n+1}\in(n-1,n+1)$.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I realized where I was not paying attention when I tried to solve by induction.